# How can I make an object face or locate to the active camera?

Tags: rigging, constraints, makehuman

I want the eyes of a character to rotate to look in the direction of a specific point.

I have a rig for the eyes of a character and I want the part of the rig that controls the eyes to be at the active camera, the rig crosses the eyes to its location and thus the character looks to that specific point. Also, I want the head rig to face the active camera. I just need to know if and how I can make the two bones snap to the active camera.

Comment: You want specific bones to [rotate] towards some other object? Is that correct?

Comment: I have a setup like the one below, I need to know how to specify which camera is the active camera, and thus, the object the rig should follow.

Answer (score 5):

- Consider a [track to] constraint which rotates the bones

[image]

[image]

- You can track to the camera or some object like two rectangles next to each other lets call them a pair of eye trackables, similar in placement to a pair of eye glasses. Depicted above in the animation is an example. Left eye tracks left point, right eye tracks right point.  The points are eye distance apart.  At a far distance the eye trackables cause the eyes to rotate and be nearly parallel.  At a close distance the this can prevent crossed eye problem.  Some blender people might say the having a separate eye trackables is more flexible than tracking to the camera.  You can move the trackables independent of the camera.
- Consider searching Blender Facial Rig Eyes

Comment: A very complete answer. Up voted.