# Eyeball doesn't rotate well while rigging eyes

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I'm trying to make the tutorial called "`Eye Rigging in Blender`" found here :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCGekumdLLU

From minute 3.56 to minute 4.27 he links the bone to the left eye. I tried to do the same with my character. So,In `object mode` I selected the middle of my eyeball by pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to Center of Mass* and then,with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> I created a new bone and then I have selected the eye and with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> I selected also the bone,finally I linked the bone with the center of the eye pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then `Parent to Bone`. The problem is that my eyeball doesn't rotate like the one on the video. Which keys he pressed on minute 5:07 to rotate the eyeball in that way ? I rotate my eyeball using <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> ; <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> ; <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> but it does only in one direction.

This is how my eyeball rotates :

http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-14_16-54-46.mp4

you can see there is something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Your pivot point is the 3D Cursor and and it's not in the center of the eye.`Shift + S` > Cursor to selected. minute 3:17 in your tutorial

Comment: Did it,but I don't know if the problem is fixed because I still don't know which keys the author of the tutorial pressed to move the eye in all directions,since I have to press R + x or R + y or R + z separately to move the eye in these different directions.

Comment: he rotates with the [3D Transform Manipulator](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/rotate.html#rotation-with-the-3d-transform-manipulator)

Comment: it does not work. I activated the "3d transform manipulator",In Pose mode I selected the bone and then I rotated the eye,but it didn't rotate like one on the tutorial,check this : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-14_18-39-01.mp4

Comment: here also does not work with the corrected pivot point ? --> http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-14_18-46-02.mp4

Comment: Consider .... http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31711/how-can-i-make-an-object-face-or-locate-to-the-active-camera/31715#31715

Comment: Please place a screen image in your question to clarify your question.  The armature Jorge created has bone to control the head with other attached bones to control the eye. The location of the eyebone was constrained by the whole structure.  Copy his whole armature structure.  In your video you seem to be moving a single bone around freely in and out of the socket which is a defect and problem.  That will cause you, and viewer, and the eyeball hardship.  The attempted short cut has become the long extension of work.  You need the whole head armature to allow the eyebone to ONLY rotate.

Comment: Jorge didn't use neither bone constraint nor he disabled the "deform" checkbox when he linked the bone to the left eye !

Comment: If I have to build the whole armature to constrain the location of the eyebome,why it is constrained before completing its construction?