# The eyeballs of my character don't rotate well

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I'm trying to rotate correctly the eyeballs of my character,that I have previously rigged with rigify modded by pitchipoi. The problem is that they don't rotate well. For those who say what this question is the duplicated of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50742/eyeball-doesnt-rotate-well-while-rigging-eyes),I reply that I compared this character with the first character that I rigged perfectly to see what could be wrong and for example I saw that :

1) the pivot point of the bone eye.L is set to "median point",like the new one ;

2) the transformation manipulator is set to "translate" like the new one ;

3) the eye is parented with the rig (now called rig.girl) and the MCH-eye.L control bone,like the new one ;

4) the origin point is set to the center of the mass of the eyeball,like the new one. No others things that could be broken come to my mind.

5) This [user](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/6076/atomicbezierslinger) in the duplicated post,said to "Copy his whole armature structure",so,since I used the default armature provided by rigify and pitchipoi,without doing changes,I think that I did it.

You can see how works the working character,[here](https://sendvid.com/4fllt2s8)

and you can see how works the new character,[here](https://sendvid.com/ky04qycz)

So,what else ?

Comment: Please provide your .blend file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you

Comment: http://www47.zippyshare.com/v/If6xrZDE/file.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also noticed this Blender behaviour. When you're choosing the parent name from the box, or using eyedropper, it doesn't work properly. The solution is to select the eye object, Shift select the MCH-eye.L in pose mode, press CTRL+P and choose Bone. Then it will work properly. Unfortunately I don't know why it's like that, just know working solution.

Comment: your solution worked partially on the blender file that I have attached here,but worked perfectly after that I have generated a new final rig,probably because the attached file has some other unknown problem.