# I can not get "track To"constraint to work on my eyes

Tags: constraints

I have bones in the eyes names Eye.L and Eye.R I have bones in front of the eyes marked Eye_Look_At.L and Eye_Look_at.R - The course instructor says to add a "Track To" constraint on the Eye.L and Eye.R bones and choose "Armature" and the corresponding Eye look at bone. I have tried everything to try and move the eyes with the Eye_Look_At bones but nothing is working.

> blend -  https://pasteall.org/blend/58c09422bd24405191af0c587d16b8e3

[image]

Comment: Please see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31711/how-can-i-make-an-object-face-or-locate-to-the-active-camera/31715#31715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to choose the right *Track To* direction, i.e. the bone axis that is supposed to point towards the *Target*, which in this case is *Y*, and it seems to work fine:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get the eyes moving using the track to constraint bones. But when the constraint is on the eyes are cross-eyed and when the constraint is off they are normal. Could you tell me how I can fix this? .blend ---> https://pasteall.org/blend/f9583f5c96944895a5d62272d21c4f5f

Comment: you need to put the bone head at the same location as the eye sphere origin

Comment: Can you explain how I would go about doing that? I am a bone head.

Comment: select the eye object, make sure that the origin is at its center, then shift S > 3D cursor at selected, then select the bone head (the sphere at the base of the bone) and shift S again > Selection to 3D cursor, so that the rotation center of the bone is at the same point as the eye rotation center

Comment: Can you recommend a course that will actually teach me how to learn blender?

Comment: you can find a lot of tutorials on Youtube, like Grant Abbitt's and many others, it depends on what you want to learn

Comment: The problem is solved and it was such a simple fix. I checked the box next to "Target Z" and the eye rig is fine now. I do not know why it worked, but it did! Thank you for all the help. I need all the help I can get trying to learn this Blender thing.

Comment: oh ok it looks like it worked for me so I may have missed something  ;)